# how to shutdown tomcat embedded gracefully (without spring)

Tags: java, tomcat

I created sample projects to understand how to use tomcat embedded:
[tomcat embedded 9 with javax](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.tst.tomcat.embedded.gwt)
[tomcat embedded 10 with jakarta](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.tst.tomcat.embedded)

On ServletDestroy, in below order:

- I destroyed connectors.
- I wait 5 seconds.
- I destroyed context.
- I wait 5 seconds.
- I stopped tomcat.
- I wait 5 seconds.
- I destroyed tomcat.

But it does not shutdown gracefully; function TS_TomcatListener.contextDestroyed never called.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: I learned that I should use inorder: tomcat.stop; tomcat.destroy; @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67804452/embedded-tomcat-running-as-windows-service-takes-long-time-to-stop-the-service?rq=1 I will check it, wheater it fixes the problem

Comment: When i look into code deeply, I figured out that WebServlet created by Annotation is not seeing the static Tomcat Object. So it does not process shutdown at all. I will try to add the servlet by mapping (without annotation) while sending the Tomcat object on its contructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason Servlet classes attached to context by annotation cannot read static objects.
I fixed this issue, by sending tomcat object while constructing the ServletDestroy class and mapped it to contexed manually.